# System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Priority

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am receving this error:

using the following code

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 class CategoriesListBoxDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate
            SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

            if (element != null && item != null && item is Task)
            {
                Task taskitem = item as Task;

                if (taskitem.Priority == 1)
                    return
                        element.FindResource("importantTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                else
                    return
                        element.FindResource("myTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: That's just it, tasks don't have a `Priority` property... How do *you* expect this to be fixed?

Comment: The code was taken for an example from MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx maybe some error in the documentation

Comment: Could you suggest me an alternative approach?

Comment: I think they're referring to a user-defined `Task` class, not to `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding this lies in the description of the example:

> In this example, the binding source is a list of `Task` objects. One of the properties of a `Task` object is `Priority`. There are two data templates defined, `myTaskTemplate` and `importantTaskTemplate`.

What this means in the `Task` class in the example is fictional. You are expected to provide your own representation of an item, and use one or more properties of that item to determine some appropriate `DataTemplate` to apply for that item.

Comment: Good find, I wouldn't have found that myself.

Comment: Thanks I actually missed this line in that example :-) thanks